# Изменить данные в таблице MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с товарами. `id, title, price`. Очень много данных, и нужно написать скрипт который будет увеличивать цену в процентном соотношении.

Например: Товар с ценой 1000. Нужно чтобы увеличил на 10%. Соответственно нужно, что бы это все работало на стороне MySQL.

Я сделал так: Получаю данные, потом  гоняю их в цикле, увеличивая цену и записываю в БД. Неочень правильно. А как составить запрос который увеличит все значения на стороне MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/5006740

если вы хотите просто проапдейтить все товары на 10 процентов:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `price` = `price`  + (`price`/100)*10;
```

#10 - это ваш переменный процент, из скрипта его вставляйте

Comment: `price = price / 100 * 110;` или `price = price * 1.10;`

Comment: ну возможно процент у него меняться будет.

Comment: И что? Высшая математика там с процентами? :)

Comment: да пусть он как угодно его вычисляет) у вас тоже хороший ответ